# I am trying to access var declare as global & calculated in $scope.funcName in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hello everyone can anyone help me....
I am trying to access var declare as global & calculated in $scope.funcName in angularJS

**1. HTML**

```
  {{totalmarks}}
```

**2. Controller**

```
var next = 0;
  var marks = 0;
  var total;
  $http.get('../js/commonquiz.json').success(function(res){
  $scope.myData = res;
  jsonData = $scope.myData;
  noOfQuestion = jsonData.length;
  $scope.currentQ = jsonData[next];
  }).error(function (err){
  console.log(err);
  });
  $scope.change_question = function(selected,option,index){
  var rightAns = $scope.currentQ.result //Get Result value
  if (index == rightAns){ //compare selected value with rightANS
  $scope.rightOption = index;
  marks = marks + 1;
  total = marks;
  } 
  }
  $scope.totalmarks = total;
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: question? and write neat code